# darken image onClick

Tags: javascript, image, function, onclick

I have a question regarding a javascript function. To get started, my code looks like this:

```
Game.mushroom = function(myX, myY){
var my = new createjs.Bitmap("img/small-mushroom.png");
my.x = myX;
my.y = myY;

my.onClick = function(){
    my.rotation += 10;
    Game.stage.update();
}
return my;
}
```

At the moment when I click my little mushroom it is rotation around center point when you click on it.

What I was planning to do was creating an onClick function that when you would click the image it would instead give the image dark opacity over it.

I have no idea how to execute it so I ask for your help, to construct something similar to the rotation click function.

(I am using the EaseJS framework too)

Comment: Is this in a browser or no?

Comment: This code block is taken straight from my codeprogram, not from the browser if that is what you are asking.

Comment: OK, simple solution would have been CSS.  I'm not nearly familiar enough with JS outside of a browser to help with this, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your input though, but yes CSS would do the trick but I want it to be coded in the same way as the click function shown in my code :)

Comment: EaselJS or easejs?  http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Bitmap.html (see Properties tab, alpha & filters)

Comment: There we go, I can definitely work with that for starters. Thanks MaKR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaKR pointed out a link in the comment section:

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Bitmap.html

I can use that for now, if you have more solutions, please just throw them in here!